# Virtual networking devices in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtual, tap

Can someone explain in detail what are the differences of veth pairs and tap interfaces and how these devices connect to linux bridge or openvswitch.

I found this:
"Veth is a special net devices which were created in pair, I consider it as a method to change the traffic's direction, that is, when the out direction traffic is sent to veth device from Linux protocol stack, it was sent to another its mirror veth device, so the mirror one treats it as a in direction traffic and put it back to Linux protocol stack for further usage.

Tap device is logical net device but have different with any other one: it allows user space program directly injecting traffic into Linux protocol stack, as well as it can retrieve traffic from the stack. It opens a tunnel to Linux protocol stack at level 2(or tun device at level 3) in user space, the stack will consider data from user space as in direction traffic"

but it didn't gave me the whole picture.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Question better on superuser.com? See introduction to linux virtual networking . . . http://superuser.com/questions/428694/creating-a-new-network-namespace-on-linux/817118#817118

Answer (score 17):

Linux tap interfaces created with ip tuntap cannot be **used to attach network namespaces** to linuxbridges or the openvswitch so we need to depend upon veth pair.

Virtual Ethernet interfaces come in pairs, and they are connected like a tube—whatever comes in one veth interface will come out the other peer veth interface.
As a result, you can use veth interfaces **to connect a network namespace** to the outside world via the “default” or “global” namespace where physical 
interfaces exist.

A TAP device, such as vnet0 is how hypervisors such as KVM and Xen implement a virtual network interface card (**typically called a VIF or vNIC**). 
An Ethernet frame sent to a TAP device is received by the guest operating system.

Answer (score 17):

The purpose of these virtual networking artifacts are similar. But there are subtle differences and hence they are used in different circumstances:

1. **TAP**: The user-space application/VM  can read or write an ethernet frame to the tap interface and it would reach the host kernel, where it would be handled like any other ethernet frame that reached the kernel via physical (e.g. eth0) ports. You can potentially add it to a software-bridge (e.g. linux-bridge)
2. **VETH**: Typically used when you are trying to connect two entities which would want to "get hold of" (for lack of better phrase) an interface to forward/receive frames. These entities could be containers/bridges/ovs-switch etc. Say you want to connect a docker/lxc container to OVS. You can create a veth pair and push the first interface to the docker/lxc (say, as a phys interface) and push the other interface to OVS. You cannot do this with TAP.

Please note that we should not misconstrue that we need to use VETH and not tap when using the OVS. We can always create the internal ports in OVS which behave exactly like the tap interface. But this is not always possible, for instance when you want to connect to an entity that cannot synthesise a tap-like interface. I.e.:

```
$ ovs-vsctl add-port ovs-switch-name tap0
```

Now you can use `tap0` like we use the tap interfaces.